# Вывод на маркеров на свой слой карты Яндекс из БД

Tags: java, яндекс-карты

Нужна помощь в создании карты для игрового проекта, а точнее у меня слой карты поверх обычной, мне надо чтобы маркера выводились из БД на карту.

**Структура базы**

```
CREATE TABLE `bizz1` ( 
`id` smallint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`owner` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No-one', 
`message` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None', 
`ent_x` float(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000', 
`ent_y` float(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000', 
`price` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `owner` (`owner`), 
KEY `owned` (`owned`) 
)
```

`ent_x` и `ent_y` это положение маркера по `х` и `у`,  `owner` это хозяин бизнеса, `message` имя бизнеса и `price` - цена

Данные на карту выводились из `json` файла, поэтому вот код карты:

```
var map,

    objectManager,

    layerName = "user#layer";

ymaps.ready(onReady);

function onReady () {

    setupLayer();

    setupMap();

    setupPresets();

    setupPlaces();

}

function setupLayer () {

    var Layer = function () {

        var layer = new ymaps.Layer("./map/%z/%x-%y.jpg", {

            //tileTransparent: true,

            notFoundTile: "./map/ocean/0-0.jpg"

        });

        layer.getZoomRange = function () {

                    return ymaps.vow.resolve([0,4]);

                };

                return layer;

    };

    ymaps.layer.storage.add(layerName, Layer);

    var mapType = new ymaps.MapType(layerName, [layerName]);

    ymaps.mapType.storage.add(layerName, mapType);

}

function setupMap () {

    map = new ymaps.Map('map', {

        center: [0, 0],

        zoom: 2,

        controls: ['zoomControl'],

        type: layerName

    }, {

        projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[-10, -10], [10, 10]], [false, false])

    });

}

function setupPresets () {

    ymaps.option.presetStorage

        .add('casino', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/casino.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('bank', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/bank.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('car', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/car.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('weapon', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/weapon.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('bizz', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/bizz.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('dateDrink', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/dateDrink.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('SWEET', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/SWEET.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('chicken', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/chicken.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('pizza', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/pizza.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('dateFood', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/dateFood.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('burgerShot', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/burgerShot.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('diner', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/diner.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('clothes', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/clothes.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('Attack', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/Attack.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        })

        .add('ZERO', {

            iconLayout: 'default#image',

            iconImageHref: './map/icons/ZERO.png',

            iconImageSize: [30, 30],

            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]

        });

}

function setupPlaces () {

    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();

   objectManager.add($markers);

   map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    //Определение координат клика

    map.events.add('click', function (e) {

        if (!map.balloon.isOpen()) {

            var coords = e.get('coords');

            map.balloon.open(coords, {

                contentHeader:'Опеределение координат!',

                contentBody:

                    [

                    coords[0].toPrecision(6),

                    coords[1].toPrecision(6)

                    ].join(', ') + '</p>',

                contentFooter:'<sup>Щелкните еще раз</sup>'

            });

        }

        else {

            map.balloon.close();

        }

    });

    // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке

    // правой кнопки мыши в любой точке карты.

    // При возникновении такого события покажем всплывающую подсказку

    // в точке щелчка.

    map.events.add('contextmenu', function (e) {

        map.hint.open(e.get('coords'), 'Кто-то щелкнул правой кнопкой');

    });



    // Скрываем хинт при открытии балуна.

    map.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {

        map.hint.close();

    });

}
```

А в в `json`:

```
var markers = {

    "type": "FeatureCollection",

    "features": [

    {"type": "Feature", "id": 50, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.535391, -7.44418]}, "properties": {"type": "bizz","balloonContent": "<center><strong>owner[50]</strong></center><br><strong>Владелец: </strong>owner<br><strong>Оценка: </strong>price"}, "options": {"preset": "ZERO"}}
```